# Hibernate - is there any API to get a field's value of an unknown object?

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection, annotations

I want to read a field on an Unknown object returned by hibernate query. I know reflection can be used here. But is there any Hibernate API available to do that? I have only the object and value of @Column annotation.

For example: Let's say I've following class

```
class Person {
    @Column(name = "nick_name")
    String name;
}
```

When Hibernate returns this object as a part of query, I want to get the value of field name using the "nick_name" name attribute.

**EDIT:**

My requirement is to fetch the value of a specific field from object returned by Hibernate. I'll explain with an example

```
Object obj = queryHibernateForObject();
```

Let's say obj is of type Person and I  want to fetch value of "nick_name" field from this object.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clean without query, but I think you have situation like here
[Handling Unknown Objects in ArrayList](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/corejava/handling-unknown-object-in-arraylist.html)

You can work with Object[]:

```
String sql = "select s.rollNo, s.name, s.address from Student s";
Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
List list = query.list();
Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
for (Iterator it = query.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {
    Object[] object = (Object[]) it.next();
    System.out.println(object[0]);
    System.out.println(object[1]);
    System.out.println(object[2]);
}
```

Or you can use JPA query feature:

```
String sql = "select new com.some.pkg.SomeDtoClass(s.rollNo, s.name, s.address) from Student s";
Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
List<SomeDtoClass> list = (List<SomeDtoClass>)query.list();
```

It is important to specify full class name inside query. Also SomeDtoClass should have appropriate constructor.

Or you can use setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE)

```
String sql = "select s.rollNo as rollNo, s.name as name, s.address as address from Student s";
Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
List list = query.list();
Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Map map=(Map)iterator.next();
    System.out.println(map.get("rollNo"));
    System.out.println(map.get("name"));
    System.out.println(map.get("address"));
}
```

In this case it is important to use aliases in select. Otherwise you will get map keys as "0", "1", ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection:

```
public static <T> getFieldByColumnName(Object obj, String columnName) throws Exception {
    for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        Annotation a = field.getAnnotation(Column.class);
        if (a != null && a.getValue().equals(columnName)) {
            return <T> field.get(obj);
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such column:" + columnName);
}
```

Disclaimer: Thumbed in on iPhone from memory - there could be syntax errors.